# Finding and debugging bad record using hive

Tags: mapreduce, hive, bigdata

Is there any way to pinpoint the badrecord when we are loading the data using hive or while processing the data.

The scenario Goes like this.
Suppose I have file that need to be loaded as table using hive which got 1 Million records in it. Delimited by some '|' symbol.

So suppose after Half a million record processing I encounter a problem. IS there anyway to debug it or precisely pinpoint the record/records having the issues.

If you are not clear about my question please let me know. 
I know there is a skipping of bad record in mapreduce (Kind of percentage). I would like to get this in the perspective of hive.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Has Anybody got any idea about the above question. Or is the Question doesn't make sense?

Comment: Hi did you get answer to this question, I'm facing kind of same issue.